# どこまでを1つのクラスとするかの基本的な考え方

Tags: game-development

ゲームアプリを素人ながら作っているのですが、
複数種類の敵をenemyというクラスひとまとめにして、各敵をインスタンスとして生成するのか
それとも種類毎にenemy1、enemy2といったクラスを作り、各個体毎にインスタンスを作るのか
似たような敵はクラスをまとめるて作るのか
プロはどうされているのでしょうか。

例えばマリオの敵であるクリボー、ノコノコ、パタパタを例に挙げると
クリボーもノコノコもパタパタも敵クラスで生成するのか
クリボークラス、ノコノコクラス、パタパタクラスを生成するのか
クリボークラス、カメクラスを生成するのか

結局は、可読性と作りやすさで臨機応変に対応するのが適切なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

折角オブジェクト指向でプログラムしているのですから、敵キャラというクラスを作成し、当たり判定などの共通の実装をここで定義し、キャラの種類のサブクラスでそのキャラ独特の振る舞いを差分でコーディングするのが一番ではないでしょうか？
今回の例で言うと

ennemy という親クラスを定義し、enemy1, enemy2というサブクラスを定義し、enemy1, enemy2...のインスタンスを生成するといった感じになるでしょうか。

Comment: 基本的には私もそうします。
が、私ならキャラ独特の動きはStrategyパターンで実装します。
それなら見た目クリボーの動きノコノコとかを作りやすいので。

Comment: ありがとうございます。クラスの継承とはそうやって使うんですね。駆け出しの自分にとって目からうろこです。